# Finite amount of consecutive smooth numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

is there a short proof of the fact that there is a finite amount of consecutive smooth numbers (meaning Given a finite set B, there is a finite amount of pairs $n,n+1$ so that both can be expressed as the product of elements from B only.

I was told there is a proof via the Thue–Siegel–Roth theorem but the proof of the theorem is pretty long and I'd be happy if there was another proof.

Answer (score 2):

D. H. Lehmer's paper [On a problem of Størmer](https://www.projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256067456) provides a short proof of conditions necessary to be a consecutive smooth pair, a method to find all such pairs, and some weak upper bounds. It assumes familiarity with some number theory and Pell's equation. Størmer's original paper also includes a theorem of finiteness and a procedure.